# Joblib doesn't call a custom function when n_jobs > 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, joblib, parallelism-amdahl

I have an example with data.

As you can see from the code, every call of a function `fit_by_idx()` has to print `'here'`, but it doesn't. All is ok when `n_jobs=1`, but if `n_jobs` is more, than `joblib` does not call the function.

Code:

```
import statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters as holtwinters
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

train = pd.read_csv('train.csv').drop(columns=['id'])


def iter_predict(data, model, steps, fit_args=[],  fit_kwargs={}): # steps - кол. предсказываемых точек
    def fit_by_idx(idx):
        print('here')
        endog = data.iloc[idx]
        fitted = model(endog).fit(*fit_args, optimized=False, **fit_kwargs)\
        res[idx, :] = fitted.forecast(steps)

    res = np.zeros((data.shape[0], steps))
    Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(fit_by_idx)(idx) for idx in range(data.shape[0]))
    return res

iter_predict(train, holtwinters.SimpleExpSmoothing, 2, fit_kwargs={'smoothing_level': 0.5})
```

And here's the link to the [dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TcoyHYjKPuwFW4PNBUB0TT6RqtdpzvSv).

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : "*if **`n_jobs`** is more, than **`joblib` does not call the function**.*"

Well, it does ( you may check the PID & PPID numbers ),
it just does not present the result of the `print( "here" )`

Using the definition from API documentation :

> `print( *objects, sep = ' ', end = '\n', file = sys.stdout, flush = False )`
>   start with enforcing the **`flush = True`**

Yet, going to face more troubles down the road. `joblib`-spawns ( unless forced otherwise, at a cost of adverse effects on performance, if returning back to a pure-`[SERIAL]`, GIL-controlled re-`[SERIAL]`-ised code execution for any `n_jobs` running again one-step-after-another-after-another, which does not make sense, as you pay all the costs of instantiations and other overheads, yet not receiving any speed-up benefit from doing so, does it? ). [Using:](https://tio.run/##tVbvT@NGEP3uv2IUPiSRHAt6lZDcgnR3wIlKDYjkepU4ZG3sDd7G3rV214AP8bdzb9c2gUCrUq6WcMz@ePNm3szsVo3NlXx3f18xY36h9hFlpbQlWZdVQ8yQrIIXppUJllqV9JdaFGLRj54yzYqCFyFlvGANz0KquqFkwdIVl1kQTJPfTj7MaI92g2A4HBJN3vacf3l/Nj2efroIPMG5IpMzzWlZy9QKJcFlKaTwnyzVyhgq68KKquBU@QhQpVXKjeEmbDGEJQHPuRtkuiGrSPOiIYdAhmvBCvGNeURstSpVRUTznJOxTGZMZy1MP0dC9pYAW4l0BdOLGkascewY6LgQFrzk0nrcjock@wiVEGrt@OTQxfArjtBirBTtHhPRkdLY5NanfO1LyqRU9oH4OjSGrnOR5uTC5aPEM2y3wMX0FTxuITyoZ5IkJRMySahUWV3wqJ2Pou7jeEmNqj2cC5Wkz9PjP8k0xvIy9FOgQuZaWBh1CeEi63BV0YWsVaaVQ8hL6rImoi/C5liK@HVD4VOmPf8WZu2gM7jgbUpkdN2icLpWesX1WniqvTlMdQDM2E6pVlnnN9QzNe9BQMWoovZZgG@bM9uidAiw4NyDGKgMZ7MzRgvN2co8Vfb0ZIZI4Z92s2OdsyvY4kI/0gSmeusYRm3ZpksKAR9M7bQ0LURXwDIjVXG5KJiJXLkFAQKFpOA6qRARkdoRZcyykB49W6hk8DJ0cDRBxqy4XxLQs2dLwQsNwS8NKqRUV4gxHKffP/5xOEkL0LLNC9vGceBHHZWlsMmiSUR2MyK8MEdb/67ujz5PP86PT6YXE@BMfvWB3nf1D72tZtIsuXaiQwTOEBlH0PJJ27ImviUwi/lOlxE34@CBbKUR9BEN4R4/v92Ok/2fs7vR6enxQYy/vdsdjOxmd/HtT3HsPsYXwwiel8x6N8IXvH79o0x0yW1ViWw0DqGK5cjKjv@G@73D5Aj7JImpYOUiY3SDXjtI4MNdMqCYbh54Poan8Y9k7BHpf2Pcwv8YxuPnUqG74A0KX@3g@eyyqE2O2bmu@bPJltPWm86zjbwGm32P6l8adb6HQzn6xnGUjait3gj9reLn2xchvaNeS1eI7AO65eH0wDVwZLPN0Xsy9KhhSMNCrRr3u9Fzh648e3@sbuKnTnaFMfiKY@Dvn0/KtVOsVHQ@dEIOLyZd4x48qPlA7ln2@Sa3eXVYbwhJJkgqF4nuNjGOX0iG/joyWi/fpfGov5yMHvUeN9y2@yyZHZ4lB4ezJFVVk6hlO/22XHNS/BM81EE1XPINNV9ldr0WByH8/m/CJYc3uDH4u90rhNPc1lq65AyC3s5s/v5sHpPvlq5/7mxnd4MXK9mhrNkNwo3jCcmuJEeu7@ySX3x//x0)

```
def iter_preDEMO( data,            # Pandas DF-alike data
                  #other args removed for MCVE-clarity
                  ):

    def fit_by_idx( idx ): #-------------------------------------[FUNCTION]-def-<start> To be transferred to each remote-joblib-initiated process(es)

        print( 'here[{0:_>4d}(PPID:PID={1:_>7d}:{2::>7d})]'.format( idx,
                                                                    os.getppid(), # test joblib-[FUNCTION]-def-transfer here with: lambda x = "_{0:}_" : x.format( os.getppid() )
                                                                    os.getpid()   # test joblib-[FUNCTION]-def-transfer here with: lambda x = "_{0:}_" : x.format( os.getpid()  )
                                                                    ),
                end   = "\t",
                flush = True
                )
    #------------------------------------------------------------[FUNCTION]-def-<end>

    res = np.zeros( ( data.shape[0], 3 ) )
    for aBackEND in ( 'threading', 'loky', 'multiprocessing' ):
        try:
             print( "\n____________________________Going into ['{0:}']-backend".format( aBackEND ) )
             with parallel_backend( aBackEND, n_jobs = N_JOBS ):
                  Parallel( n_jobs = N_JOBS )( delayed( fit_by_idx )( pickled_SER_DES_copy_of_idx )
                                               for                    pickled_SER_DES_copy_of_idx in range( data.shape[0] )
                                               )
        finally:
             print( "\n_____________________________Exit from ['{0:}']-backend".format( aBackEND ) )
    return res
```

you shall see how the things work, using a bit more detailed, `print()`-ed results

```
START: PID=_____22528

____________________________Going into ['threading']-backend
here[___0(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[___1(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[___2(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[___3(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[___4(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[___5(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[___6(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[___7(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[___8(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[___9(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[__10(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[__11(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[__12(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[__13(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[__14(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[__15(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[__16(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    
_____________________________Exit from ['threading']-backend

____________________________Going into ['loky']-backend
here[___0(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[___1(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[___2(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[___3(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[___4(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[___5(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[___6(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[___7(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[___8(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[___9(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[__10(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[__11(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[__12(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[__13(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[__14(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[__15(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[__16(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    
_____________________________Exit from ['loky']-backend

____________________________Going into ['multiprocessing']-backend
here[___0(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[___1(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[___2(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[___3(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[___4(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[___5(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[___6(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[___7(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[___8(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[___9(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[__10(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[__11(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[__12(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[__13(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[__14(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[__15(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    here[__16(PPID:PID=__22527:::22528)]    
_____________________________Exit from ['multiprocessing']-backend

 [[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  ...
  ]
```

Also check [this](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/833) and [this](https://tio.run/##fZDBbsMgEETvfMUqJ5AsK3VvkXzpOYr6BwjH65QGAwJayYry7S7GOLbSqlwwq/HMm7VD@DD6dRw7Z3r4NI2STcmtcEIpVLwR5yvq1oPsrXEBjuY6vM0zQs5KeA8n9AHbPKQbATsQiKfFDi4YuE66xZF6VF1WTCePoX7yY8@KMvso/EYV5fuHwGH4cnrRFXAyGgnZ9FpKvOd2RWRTYsCWTIzWSR24lS1N1vU@0@WfjN@@guwxvaeP0itES8tqhk1GtNsdE@Etud0PcDO@jHuYAth9xwhJqXMbmrNWhpfZa0GlmscOvq4Yzcz0oWW0YtAZBxykBif0BeNkCvh/qWRNY0B@JRXLJut8r9EzNKN/xo7jDw) on your O/S, resp. your actual `joblib` and (hidden) pickling-SER/DES-tools versions.